# How to read/view mac HFS+ files form 18.04.1? hfsprogs does not exist?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to read HFS+ files on Apple SSD that appears to have a broken? partition using Ubuntu 18.04.1 live usb. I performed the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hfsprogs
```

I get the following output:

> ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sudo apt-get install hfsprogs Reading package
>   lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state
>   information... Done E: Unable to locate package hfsprogs

How do I get around this?

When I attempt to use command fsck.hfsplus, the command is not found.

When I tried fsck.hfs, it says not found, but can be installed with sudo apt install hfsprogs... which yields the same output above.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ubuntu live, run this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```